# Help understanding a had-not sentence

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

> There a customer can order dishes that he would not be able to enjoy had the restaurant not established a menu on the basis of recipes, ingredients, and practice in preparation.

Could anyone tell me what does the sentence in the box mean? 
Is it grammatically correct?

Source:[image: Extracted from an unknown book]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is conditional inversion, a construction in which a condition clause is expressed by subject-auxiliary inversion instead of with *if*:

> ... if **the restaurant had** not established ...
>       ↓
>   ... **had the restaurant** not established ...

Today this is permitted only with the auxiliaries *had*, *were* and *should*, and it has rather an old-fashioned ring.

You can find many more questions about this construction by searching on the tags [conditional-constructions](/questions/tagged/conditional-constructions) and [inversion](/questions/tagged/inversion).